pytorch BatchNorm1D result different from manually implementation
I read the BatchNorm1D doc in pytorch, but I get the different result:
input  = torch.tensor([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])

1.using BatchNorm1D
m  = nn.BatchNorm1d(3)
output = m(input)

output:
[[-1.0, -1.0, -1.0],[ 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]]

2.hard coding
output = (input-input.mean(dim=0))/input.std(dim=0)

output:
[[-0.7071, -0.7071, -0.7071],[0.7071, 0.7071, 0.7071]]

But they get the different result, why?

By default, Bessel's correction is used when computing the standard deviation in PyTorch with torch.std. Up until 1.13, this parameter was called "unbiased", but in 2.0, it was renamed to "correction". To replicate the behavior of a batch normalization layer, you should not use the default correction:

versions 1.*:
(input-input.mean(dim=0))/input.std(dim=0, unbiased=False)


versions 2.*:
(input-input.mean(dim=0))/input.std(dim=0, correction=0)



